# Compare 2 large SQL queries without hitting the DataBase

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, integration-testing

I have a component in MICRO service which is responsible for building a a query which can be used to retrieve records from another component.

I am in a need to come up with an integration test to check if query retrieved from component is same with a response stored in file.

Problems in string based comparisons are

1. Different ordering of sub queries
2. Different ordering of join statements

I initially tried string based comparisons without this reordering behavior but this approach wont work.

> Query will be looking something like this

```
WITH dataTab0 AS 
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(to_date(tab_0_0.times),'YYYYMMDD')  AS 
        TIME_ID_CATEGORY,tab_0_0.request_id AS PAGE_IMPRESSION  
    FROM full_contents_2 AS tab_0_0  
        WHERE  ( ( tab_0_0.times >= date'2018-11-16') 
    and ( tab_0_0.times < date'2018-12-14') 
    and ( mod(coalesce(tab_0_0.ieid,5),5)  = 0))     ) ,
dataTab1 AS 
    (SELECT calcTab0.TIME_ID_CATEGORY,calcTab0.SUM_OF_GROUP,calcTab0.PAGE_IMPRESSION  
    FROM (SELECT coalesce(inner0.TIME_ID_CATEGORY,'<<<sum\>>>') AS 
             TIME_ID_CATEGORY,inner0.SUM_OF_GROUP,inner0.PAGE_IMPRESSION  
    FROM (SELECT coalesce(t0.TIME_ID_CATEGORY,'<<null>>') AS TIME_ID_CATEGORY,log2(grouping(coalesce(t0.TIME_ID_CATEGORY,'<<null>>'))+ 1) AS SUM_OF_GROUP,COUNT( t0.PAGE_IMPRESSION) AS PAGE_IMPRESSION  
    FROM dataTab0 AS t0  
        WHERE  t0.TIME_ID_CATEGORY is not null   
    GROUP BY rollup( 1)   ) AS inner0 
    WHERE  SUM_OF_GROUP = 0     ) AS calcTab0     ) SELECT TIME_ID_CATEGORY,cast(SUM_OF_GROUP AS decimal)  AS SUM_OF_GROUP,PAGE_IMPRESSION  FROM dataTab1     ORDER BY 1 DESC nulls last  ;
```

I need to some how come up with a test to make sure queries are same.

Comment: Testing that the *queries* are the same sounds pretty odd. Why don't you test that the results of the query/queries are correct? Even if you did test that the queries are generated correctly, going for String comparison is pretty much the worst solution.

Comment: The entire module is responsible for giving just a query which will be used by the calling component. We did this to scale the query generation part. It might sound weird, but unfortunately that's the requirement.

Comment: If the generated query and the file will always contain the exact same characters, ignoring non functional whitespaces, could you perform some operation on the strings then hash them and compare the hashes?

Comment: I am not sure if this is correct approach. Sometimes alias names are different i.e calcTab0, calcTab1 etc.